# Challenge question; How do I prove the expected value of the following?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

It's a little tricky to me, I am not sure how to proceed...my atempt was to stick strictly to the definitions given and the formula for the (continuous) expected value.

> Prove that $E[e^{\mu+\sigma Z}\mathbb{1}_{Z>-d}]=e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma ^2}{2}}\Phi(d+\sigma)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function, $Z  \sim N(0,1)$(i.e. standard normal distribution) and $\mathbb{1}_{Z>-d}$ denotes the following indicator function of an event such that,
>
> $$\mathbb{1}_{Z>-d}=1 \text{ when } Z >-d \text{ and, } \mathbb{1}_{Z>-d}=0 \text{  otherwise}$$
>
> during your work, denote the standard normal density function as $\phi$.

I only got up to thinking $e^{\mu+\sigma Z}\mathbb{1}_{Z>-d}$ is essentially just $e^{\mu+\sigma Z}$ if $Z>-d$ for some $d$ and $0$ otherwise.
And so, the expected value is defined (for continuous random variables) $E[X]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$ where $f(x)$ is the probability for each random variable $x$. I thought this would lead me to using $\phi$ and ultimately leading me to $\Phi$ in my final conclusion as in the RHS.

But I am not sure about how to proceed, would someone please help me? It would be great if you could explain the steps to me...thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
\int^{-d}_{-\infty} 0\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mu + \sigma Z}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{Z^2}{2}}dZ +  \int_{-d}^{\infty}1\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mu + \sigma Z}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{Z^2}{2}}dZ
$$
can you integrate this?

$$
\mu + \sigma z-\frac{z^2}{2} = -\frac{z^2-2\sigma z}{2}+\mu=-\frac{(z-\sigma)^2}{2}+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+\mu
$$
thus the integral becomes
$$
\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+\mu}\int_{-d}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(z-\sigma)^2}{2}}dz
$$

Comment: That looks like it might get me to the RHS! I'll try....

Comment: I get a polynomial power so do I use integretion by parts here...?

Comment: Thanks for a massive hint. So I suspect I should use an interchange of variables...I set $y=z-\sigma$ which I get $dy=dz$ so by substitution, I get something similar. My one last question is...since $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{- \frac{y^2}{2}} dy$, how do I get the coefficient $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ from the form you've derived? $\Phi(d+ \sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{d+ \sigma}e^{- \frac{y^2}{2}} dy$ is what I need, right? Sorry to ask so much!

Comment: Sorry about the delay. The coefficient comes from the normal distribution that I am integrating with (I didn't add it because i was focused on the integral).

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes it clear, thanks!